# Display record count in custom report on the basis of row count. Magento 1.9 custom report

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, php-7.2, custom-reports

In my Custom Report.

I have created a collection which count is 25.

But After this I have applied some joins on that by another collection.

but on which I have made join is returning 25 records.

and after making join my final output is only one row but the first one collection returns 25 record.

I want that count should be 1 instead of 25.

[image]

check for reference with code
[Set custom Record Count to Collection pagination in Report Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/274561/69083)