# Set custom Record Count to Collection pagination in Report Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, php, collection

How we can set count of collection size before setting for the grid.

**Main Sales collection:**

```
$collection=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' =>$fromDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' =>$toDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq'=>Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));
```

**Had join on that Collection:**

```
$Table = Mage::getModel('amorderattr/attribute')->getResource()->getTable('amorderattr/order_attribute');
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('custom_attributes' => $amastyTable), 'main_table.entity_id = custom_attributes.order_id',array('is_first_order'));
```

**Another Collection loaded :**

```
$CustomersCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$newCustomersCollection = $CustomersCollection
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));
if(strlen($storeId)==1)
    $newCustomersCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId()));
else if($storeArr){
    $newCustomersCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeArr[0])->getWebsiteId()));
}
$newCustomers = count($newCustomersCollection);
```

**time periods :**

```
$frm = date("d M Y", strtotime($filterData->getData('from')));
$to = date("d M Y", strtotime($filterData->getData('to')));
$period=(string)$frm." - ". (string)$to;
```

**Another Collection :**

```
$totalAccountsCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
if(strlen($storeId)==1)
    $totalAccountsCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId()));
else if($storeArr){
    $totalAccountsCollection->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeArr[0])->getWebsiteId()));
}
$totalAccounts=count($totalAccountsCollection);
```

**Again different collection Loaded:**

```
$CustomersCollection1 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));;

$i=0;
foreach ($CustomersCollection1->getData() as $customer) {
    $salesOrderCollection2 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customer['entity_id']));
    if(!count($salesOrderCollection2->getData())) {
        $i++;
    }
}
$customer_having_account_but_no_order = $i;
```

**Again some other Info loaded :**

```
/* Total Customer Of USD Website starts */
$USDCustomersCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$USDCustomersCollection
    ->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>1))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));;
$USDAccounts=count($USDCustomersCollection->getData());
/* Total Customer Of USD Website ends */

/* Total Customer Of EURO Website starts */
$EUROCustomersCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$EUROCustomersCollection
    ->addFieldToFilter('website_id',array('eq'=>2))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',array('from'=>$fromDate,'to'=>$toDate));;
$EUROAccounts=count($EUROCustomersCollection->getData());
/* Total Customer Of EURO Website starts */
```

**And Finally selecting Columns from it :**

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns('COUNT(*) as total_orders')
    ->columns('SUM(custom_attributes.is_first_order) as first_order')
    ->columns('SUM(main_table.customer_is_guest) as is_guest')
    ->columns('COUNT(*) - (SUM(main_table.customer_is_guest) + SUM(custom_attributes.is_first_order)) as returning_accounts');

$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('new_accounts_created' => new Zend_Db_Expr($newCustomers)))
    ->columns(array('period' => new Zend_Db_Expr("'".$period."'")))
    ->columns(array('customer_having_account_but_no_order' => new Zend_Db_Expr($customer_having_account_but_no_order)))
    ->columns(array('usd_customer_account' => new Zend_Db_Expr($USDAccounts)))
    ->columns(array('euro_customer_account' => new Zend_Db_Expr($EUROAccounts)))
    ->columns(array('total_accounts' => new Zend_Db_Expr($totalAccounts)));
```

**And Lastly setting my colletion in prepareCollection :**

```
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

I have to to optimize it and at final setting collection to  $this->setCollection() this method it is taking 25 count as result but i get only one row in out put .

Therefore my pagination in of grid showing 25 records instead of 1(row which is getting)

[image: Check refernce image]

Comment: why you not use the group by query in collection

Comment: for which collection is it good to use group by ?